# How to conditionally fill data in column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to fill a new pandas data-frame column based on conditions.

df = Name, Mobile , Age, new_column

```
Mobile number begins with 99. new column = 9X Series
Mobile number begins with 88. new column = 8X Series
no mobile number. new_column = 'no mobile with user'
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Use `np.select([cond1,cond2...],[result1,result2...])`.

Comment: @HenryYik - any documentation / link for the same ? My focus is more on the missing data filling.